# New Relic graph zoom out

Tags: newrelic

How can I zoom out on the New Relic graph? I must close the browser panel and open New Relic again in a new panel. Can I zoom out more comfortably?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you wish to change the time period displayed on the graph, you di that by selecting the 'time picker' in the upper right corner of the dashboard right under the name of your account.  By default it will show 'Last 30 minutes Ending now'. Click on that and a selector gadget will appear allowing you to change the time period displayed.

You can read more about this in the documentation:
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/site/timepicker-setting-time-periods-to-view-data

Answer (score 0):

There's no shortcut to zoom out like using your mouse. The only way is selecting the date picker as what the reengland mentioned